# Get a list of services programatically

Tags: 8

I've recently started working with Drupal 8. I'm looking for a way to programatically(no drupal console or other CLI thing) get a list of all the services available.

Since it's built on top of Symfony I figured that the [container should have a list of all the available services](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/Container.php#L67). Well, I was wrong.

I've searched around and I can't find any specific answers, other than the CLI option, which is not what I'm looking for.

If anybody can point me in the right direction here, I'd be grateful.

Comment: To be honest, command line in Drupal 8 is almost a requirement for any development.

Comment: Agreed. But it this particular case it's not useful. I'm working a module that requires a full list of services. I haven't figured out a way(without using `shell_exec` or something of the sort) to get said list of services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all services from the container by using the kernel method `getCachedContainerDefinition()`:

```
$container = \Drupal::getContainer();
$kernel = $container->get('kernel');
$services = $kernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()['services'];
foreach ($services as $service_id => $value) {
  $service_definition = unserialize($value);
}
```

Now you can output a list, for example containing the service id and the class name in `$service_definition['class']`.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags for services and can get list of services with same tag like this. I didn't test this code, but there is a method *findTaggedServiceIds*.

```
services:
  process_text.text_filter:
    class: Drupal\process_text\TextFilterService
    tags:
      - { name: text_filter }
```

In your controller

```
//use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('text_filter');
}
```

Comment: That's not really helping. What you wrote would imply knowing the alias for the service before hand, I don't know the aliases, hence I need a list of all services.